# Laravel filament php - what is proper way to add non-standard stuff? e.g. upload CSV -> process it

Tags: laravel-filament, filamentphp

I want to upload a CSV file, and then process it.

Now I use filament v3 with panel builder. What is the filament way to do this?

currently I am building my own custom page with a custom livewire component as described here

https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/forms/adding-a-form-to-a-livewire-component

and here

https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/panels/resources/custom-pages

I feel that this is very awkward and... cumbersome. Isn't there a much easier way to add a page and have a button inside a form field that does something a bit more unusual apart from storing a record?